# I have final Aggregate report csv file format with me how to generate html report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When im trying to open in csv file in gui mode its showing error sv' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report

How to generate html report using CSV file

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the CSV file which contains aggregated data, you can only generate it from the "raw" [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles).

When you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
```

The `result.jtl` file contains metrics for each and every [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) executed.

If you want to generate Aggregate Report - add Aggregate Report listener to JMeter test plan and open the .jtl results file using "Browse" button

[image]

If you want to generate HTML Reporting Dashboard either use Tools -> HTML Report

[image]

or use [command line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) for this like

```
jmeter -g /path/to/result.jtl /path/to/dashboard/folder
```